# How to reference getTheme non static method from static method?

Tags: java, android

I have two Activities: `MainActivity.java` and `ThemeActivity.java`. In theme activity, I would like to use `getTheme()` method in static method to call it from main activity.

ThemeActivity:

```
public static void applyCustomTheme() {
    getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.CyanTheme, true);
}
```

And then call it in MainActivity:
`applyCustomTheme();`

Error: Non-static method `getTheme()` cannot be referenced from static context.

Comment: simply use it in a non-static way

Comment: If you are not in `ThemeActivity`, you shouldn't call that method there. Instead, delay it until that activity is in the foreground.

Comment: @PavneetSingh If I use is non-staic way then, I cannot call it in another activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activities should not contain any code that needs to be referenced from other classes, as they are a catalyst for your view - keep your code compartmentalized. What I would suggest is that you create a separate class with this method in it and call it (either statically or not) from any activity or fragment that needs it.

```
public class ThemeManager {

    public static void applyCustomTheme(Context context, int styleResId) {
        context.getTheme().applyStyle(styleResId, true);
    }

}
```

With that class available, it's a simple call from anywhere you wish to call it, just pass the context as the first parameter and the themeId as the second.

```
ThemeManager.applyCustomTheme(this, R.style.CyanTheme);
```

Anytime you need to add some other theme-related functionality to your app, put it in the ThemeManager class to keep things organized, you'll be glad you did down the line.

Answer (score -1):

Have an instance of the class containing the non-static method. Change your code like this:

```
public static void applyCustomTheme() {
    (new MainActivity()).getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.CyanTheme, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried but it crashes. `                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.revittechnology.mullahnasruddin/com.revittechnology.mullahnasruddin.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: You should never instantiate an Activity - too much overhead.